# Plural noun and collective noun regarded collectively

Tags: plural-forms

A has one pencil, B has one pencil, and C has no pencil.

Can I describe it as

1. “three people have two pencils.”
2. “A group of three people has two pencils.”

Answer (score 9):

> Three people have two pencils.

This is ambiguous. My first thought is that *each* of the three has two pencils for a total of six pencils, which is not what you mean.

> A group of three people has two pencils.

This is unambiguous because **to have** is conjugated in the singular, referring to the group as a whole instead of the individual members. But no native speaker would ever say this, except when devising a math problem. Besides, I find it a little hard to comprehend how *a group of people* (as a singular entity) can own such small and personal items as pencils, especially when there are fewer pencils than members of the group.

Instead:

> Three people have two pencils **between them**.

This means exactly what you want: There are three people, and counting all of the pencils they own gives you the answer "two pencils."

Comment: Can I use “collectively” or “as a group” instead of “between them”? Three people have two pencils collectively/as a group.

Comment: No, those choices aren't idiomatic. The meaning would come across but it would sound unnatural to say it that way.

Comment: “collectively” is unusual, but I wouldn't say unnatural. (“as a group” is unnatural, though.)

Comment: @Iloveeverybody That would imply a different meaning. Having something as a group implies that they are sharing the pencils.

Answer (score 2):

As described, the group doesn't have three pencils. The natural way to express your situation is neither 1 nor 2 but:

"A and B have one pencil each, and C has no pencil."

The way you describe the context is not a group of three people sharing pencils, but two people with and one person without a pencil.  Therefore saying "Three people have two pencils" is incorrect, as this implied that C has equal access to the pencils.